# Unable to execute my Timer

Tags: java, timer

I can't understand what is wrong in this code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Timer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new Run(), 0, 5000);
    }
}
```

It's the first time I use Timer in Java and it says

> ```
>  error: cannot find symbol
>  timer.schedule(new Run(), 0, 5000);
>       ^ 
>  symbol: method schedule(new Run(), int, int)
>  location: variable timer of type Timer
> ```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an instance of your class Timer. Your class Timer does not have a method schedule. If you are trying to use [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) timer, I suggest naming your class something else

Answer (score 1):

To avoid using same class name conflicts, you should use the complete package name or the fully qualified name as:

```
java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();
timer.schedule(new Run(), 0, 5000);
```